# Open Expo based react native app with Xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, expo, native

here is my question.

I created my react native app with expo. Today I needed to open my project with xcode, but when I tried to open Xcode give me an error that´s not possible to open the folder.

Any know why?

[image]

Comment: if you created a "managed" project then the ios and android native projects are managed for you by the framework. you can run `expo prebuild` to generate the ios and android directories if you like, but then they become your responsibility to maintain. https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/